# Console line is red, but no error details on jQuery post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, firebug

I am not a noob with ajax/jQuery, but this has me scratching my head:

```
$('a').click(function () {
    console.log('click registered');

    var data = ""; // I have tried this with and without data.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/Analytics/LinkClicked",
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            console.log("MADE IT");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("OK, I see an error");
            console.log('--- ' + errorThrown + ' --- ' + textStatus + ' ---');
        }
    });
});
```

My console looks like this:

```
> click registered
> POST http://localhost/Analytics/LinkClicked (In Red)
> OK, I see an error
> ---  --- 0 ---
```

When I open the post element (firebug) it has no relevant data either. I have also dumped the XMLHttpRequest object, but it also gives me no clues.

Why am I getting no error messages?

Comment: Are you running your app on `localhost` as well? IIRC cross-domain requests will result in this.

Comment: Everything is on localhost. I have another ajax call working fine elsewhere, doing pretty much the same thing. The only difference is this snippet happens when you click to leave the current page, the other activates a popup.

Comment: I assume the `XMLHttpRequest` object may provide more info about what's happening here.